# Possible bug in iOS app when refreshing and voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, ios-app

There is a bug in the iOS app when refreshing an answer page and voting.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a question with at least two answers having the same score.
2. Upvote on of the same score answers.
3. Scroll upwards, pull up to refresh.
4. Try to vote (either up or down) a different answer that had the same score and see the following:

   > [image]
   >   (tested on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226499/152859) which at the moment got two answers with score of 3)

Error in words: (for search)

> You have already voted on this answer

Comment: Reproduced, will add steps to reproduce shortly.

Comment: OK, done. Pretty radical change, hope you're fine with it.

Comment: I'm looking at this, was able to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the fact that answers changed order after a reload caused a synchronization issue, causing you to perform a vote on the wrong answer. Thus, you would be able to perform the same voting action twice, resulting in the error you saw above.

This should be **fixed in version  0.1.30.**