# What to do with a user insulting my other personal accounts?

Tags: discussion, comments, user-accounts, account-suspension

Previously a user posted a question that doesn't expose the real problem. It's likely that it's an XY problem and that has been explained clearly why in the comments. Anyway I've posted a real solution to the unreal question and got many upvotes. But the OP didn't accept that fact and continue to insult many people, thus all the comments have been removed and the question has been closed

Then half a day after that I woke up with a ton of attacks in my facebook inbox request. I don't know how he could find my personal account but he used a lot of heavy words and said that I'm completely stupid without knowing those things are

I've checked again and saw his stackexchange account has just been suspended due to unknown reasons. But I still want to know what should be the actions in those cases?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226499/162102

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374292/harassing-email-from-user